# Prevent Access to Partial View from URL but not from Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I wrote few partial methods in my controller and it is accessing directly typing in url. I want to restrict those particular methods.I used [ChildActionOnly] Attribute to restrict it. It works fine, but I am using Ajax Call to access those methods. The Ajax call is not working in ChildActionOnly. Is there any Attribute which will block from url and allows Ajax calls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to determine whether the call is an ajax call or not and do whatever you want to do.

```
public ActionResult TestRadioButtons()
{
     if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       return new HttpNotFoundResult("Not found");

    //continue processing 
   // to do :Return something    
}
```

If you like, you may simply redirect user to another page (non ajax action method) instead of returning NotFound result.

```
if(!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent work-around, should be marked as correct by the OP! Helped me a lot today thank you!